# How to wrap the text in a `td`

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a simple dimple `table`

```html
<table><tr><td>112124 12452123 12 545212415  5415451 54154 1545154545 5414956472 546461646456 112124 12452123 12 545212415  5415451 54154 1545154545 5414956472 546461646456  112124  12452123 12 545212415  5415451 54154 1545154545 5414956472 99999 112124 12452123 12 545212415  5415451 54154 1545154545 5414956472 546461646456 112124 12452123 12 545212415  5415451 54154 1545154545 5414956472 546461646456 112124 12452123 12 545212415  5415451 54154 1545154545 5414956472 546461646456 </td><td style="font-size:80px">A A A A A A A A A A A</td></tr></table>
```

As you can see, the right hand column is very tall, while the left column has loads of empty space.

How can I make the left `td` wrap smarter, so it uses more lines, and the right "A"s will have more space horizontally. as if i would of added `style="width:60%"` to the left `td'?

Of course, I can't add the percent manually. Since it's dynamic per content. I just want to fix the wrapping/flow

PS. I tried adding `table-layout:fixed` and different options of `white-space`, but meanwhile to no avail

Thanks!

Comment: I need them to be side by side. Thats okay. but why is left td stretching so much? Why isnt it letting the right td get more space. usually tables auto-fit themselves so the columns are the same height approximately. without too much extra space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `table-layout:fixed` in the table and `word-wrap:break-word` in the `td`

```
td {

    white-space: -o-pre-wrap; 
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: pre-wrap; 
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; 
    white-space: -pre-wrap; 

}
```

**And table attribute is:**

```
table { 
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%
}
```

It just stretches every time I submit.
This page is within a div also. Do I need to set the width of the div and the table also?

Comment: thanks! worked perfectly! actually the td styling is unimportant. we need only the 2 styles in the table. thanks!

Comment: @YisroelM.Olewski -- This answer does the same as setting both `td` to `width: 50%`, which according to your question is not what you want. If you remove all `A` but one, you'll see what I mean

Comment: @YisroelM.Olewski -- As I stated in main comments, you'll need a script to calculate a proper percentage.

Comment: I see you reacted to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62741200/8620333 (and probably upvote it). I simply want to warn you that it's was a plagiarized answer so better don't encourage such answer. We should instead downvote it and flag it for moderators. Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't know that why didn't you flag it